# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the error:

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

This is my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT classtype FROM learn_users WHERE username='abcde'");

echo "my result <a href='data/$result.php'>My account</a>";
```

Comment: Check out the reference for [mysqli_result](http://php.net/mysqli_result) and it will give you an idea of how to use the object you got back from `mysqli::query()`.

Comment: you need to FETCH a row of data first: http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_row

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**The `mysqli_query()` method returns an object resource to your `$result` variable, not a string.**

You need to loop it up and then access the records. You just can't directly use it as your `$result` variable.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['classtype']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: You could also do if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {...} instead of while, if you know it is only 1 row.

Answer (score 9):

Before using the `$result` variable, you should use `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` functions.

Like this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

and use the `$row` array as you need.

Comment: They're using mysqli_ as the API here. MySQL_ does not mix with that.

Answer (score 5):

[`mysqli:query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a `mysqli_result` object, which cannot be serialized into a string.

You need to fetch the results from the object. Here's how to do it.

#### If you need a single value.

Fetch a single row from the result and then access column index 0 or using an associative key. Use the null-coalescing operator in case no rows are present in the result.

```
$result = $con->query($tourquery);  // or mysqli_query($con, $tourquery);

$tourresult = $result->fetch_array()[0] ?? '';
// OR
$tourresult = $result->fetch_array()['roomprice'] ?? '';

echo '<strong>Per room amount:  </strong>'.$tourresult;
```

#### If you need multiple values.

Use `foreach` loop to iterate over the result and fetch each row one by one. You can access each column using the column name as an array index.

```
$result = $con->query($tourquery);  // or mysqli_query($con, $tourquery);

foreach($result as $row) {
    echo '<strong>Per room amount:  </strong>'.$row['roomprice'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `query()` function returns an object, you'll want fetch a record from what's returned from that function.  Look at the examples on this [page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to learn how to print data from mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "my result <a href='data/" . htmlentities($row['classtype'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . ".php'>My account</a>";
```