# Count Number of Rows in All Tables and Echo Figure

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to count all rows in all tables, within a MySQL database. I am aware of the InnoDB issue. I would also like to point out that the connection to the database is perfectly fine, I am simply omitting that code as I deem it irrelevant to my issue.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS)
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cpus_amd'");
```

I'm then echoing the figure using PHP `echo` like so:

```
echo "<p>This database contains". $sql ."processors.</p>";
```

And I'm receiving the following error in an `error_log` file:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to
string in <file> on <line>
```

I have read through the following questions, but I'm still confused and haven't directly found a solution:

- [Get record counts for all tables in MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286039/get-record-counts-for-all-tables-in-mysql-database)
- [Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722375/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-string-in)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `$sql` is a __resultset__.... you need to `fetch` the `record` from that `resultset`.... [PHP and MySQLi 101](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: If you want to echo the number of rows that the query has found use `mysqli_num_rows($sql)`

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi Mark, thank you for the insight. I'm still new to SQL so I'm not too sure what I should do in terms of code. Which one is the correct one? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add something like this to your code :

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

where $count is the number of rows returned by the request you made.

Then you don't neet to make a sum anymore. You could also keep the SUM and write :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Then, assuming you introduced in your request "myrows" (SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) myrows...), you could retrieve the result as follows :

```
$result = $row['myrows']
```

Comment: This appears to be what I was using before. I was trying to recreate the situation to post here, but I couldn't remember what I did (I'm still new to SQL). Nevertheless, `$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);` is telling me that there is just 1 model, when I've run the code directly inside phpMyAdmin, and been told there are 48 models with `SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cpus_amd'`.

Comment: if your SQL request is made to return a single value, then mysqli_num_rows will return a single row (containing the value 48 for instance). That is why you should either : modify your request without SUM() (then it will return several rows that you'll be able to count) or keep SUM(), give, in the request, a name to the field you will retrieve ("myrows"), use mysqli_fetch_assoc(), and retrieve $row['myrows'], as I shown above

Comment: I'm now getting 48. Awesome! Thank you so much. I shall edit my question with the new code for others to see, and accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can't print or echo a query, only string. Change your query like :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($c, "SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) AS SumTableRow
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'cpus_amd'");
```

(SumTableRow) is the result of `SUM(TABLE_ROWS)`

`$sql` is a query, and it can't be echoed. The result is :

```
$sqlResult = $sql['SumTableRow'];
```

This is the result you can echo. like :

```
echo "<p>This database contains".  $sqlResult ."processors.</p>";
```

Or you can do it in one query :

```
echo "<p>This database contains". $sql['SumTableRow'] ."processors.</p>";
```

Comment: `$sql['SumTableRow'];` is giving me the following error: `Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`