# Count the duplicate rows of a table and continue the calculation

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following table in mysql database

```
database name = roulette

id | number | user

1 | 18 | John
2 | 14 | Administrator
3 | 14 | Administrator
4 | 19 | Administrator
5 | 17 | Administrator
```

Now I would like to continue in the following condition:

The System must only take into account the numbers of the "Administrator" user and continue the calculation if there is at least one duplicate.

So in my example we have the number 14 repeating at least 2 times and we will have to proceed.

I do not know how to get this number from the query. I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
$connectiondb = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$duplicates = mysqli_query($connectiondb, "SELECT number, COUNT(*) as count
FROM roulette
GROUP BY number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0");

if(mysqli_num_rows($duplicates) > 0){
        echo "There is at least one duplicate number for the selected user. We proceed.";
}
```

Plus with this query I also get the error:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not
>   be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

try using count(*) in your query and the following command to access your result set:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['classtype']."<br>";
}
```

mysqli_query returns an object resource to your variable, not a string.
refer: [Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722375/object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to-string-in)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. If the following numbers are present in the column:
13
13
14
14
15
the numbers 13 and 14 are repeated at least twice.

```
$duplicate = mysqli_query($connectiondb, "SELECT id, COUNT(number) FROM roulette WHERE user = '$user' GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(number) > 1");

echo  "Duplicate in this table: ".mysqli_num_rows($duplicate)."<br>";
```